# Black Screen Sign-in for Ubuntu 22.04: Log-in information is not working

Tags: login

I was using my computer yesterday and it was working just fine. When I went to use it the morning the super-l command was not working. I shut the system down and turned it back on - and now I have a black and white log-in screen that has Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS workstation tty1. It asks for the workstation login and password. I used the credentials that I used to login in earlier. It does not work, this is my first linux machine and I have been searching for solutions but nothings is working -- please help!

Comment: Are you able to boot into recovery mode? (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)? You should be able to get root access that way and if you enable networking before dropping into the root shell you can run apt to fix broken packages which may be causing errors at boot (https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-find-and-fix-broken-packages-on-linux/). Also, if you can get root shell prompt, check the log files to see what's going on during the boot process. Also, in the recovery mode window you can check your disks for errors as well. We need more info to help you, I think.